# Why is the Poynting Vector Symmetric in E and H?

Tags: poynting-vector

Why is the Poynting Vector symmetric in E and H? I always thought that E and B were the analogous fields, so I would think that any equation using magnetic and electric fields should be symmetric in E/B or D/H. I've seen the derivation, but I have yet to find the point where my want for symmetry is being broken.

Answer (score 2):

The discrete symmetry in Maxwell equations in vacuum is not precisely that. What Maxwell equation say is that $$\mathrm d * F=0 \qquad \mbox{and } \qquad \mathrm d F=0.$$

The theory is invariant under

$$\mathbf B \mapsto \mathbf {+E},$$ 
 $$\mathbf E \mapsto \mathbf {-B},$$

which is implemented by the Hodge dual on $F$, $F \mapsto *F$, and which leaves the Poynting vector invariant.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how this addresses the question of why $\mathbf H$ appears in the Poynting vector as opposed to $\mathbf B$?  Perhaps I'm just dense, but it's not clear to me how Hodge duality sheds light on this when we're dealing with electrodynamics in a medium.

Comment: @joshphysics Sorry it took so long to answer. You're right, my answer doesn't address the question: I'm not used to electrodynamics out of vacuum. So I'll erase it.

Answer (score 2):

The electromagnetic stress-energy tensor is
$$T^{\mu\nu} = \frac{1}{\mu_0} \left[ F^{\mu \alpha}F^\nu{}_{\alpha} - \frac{1}{4} \eta^{\mu\nu}F_{\alpha\beta} F^{\alpha\beta}\right]\text{.}$$
Its terms are antisymmetric, e.g.,:
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
T_0{}^0 &=& -\frac{1}{2}\left[\epsilon_0 E^2 + \frac{1}{\mu_0}B^2\right]\text{,}\\
T_a{}^0 &=& \epsilon_0\left[\mathbf{E}\times\mathbf{B}\right]\text{,}\\
T_0{}^a &=& \frac{1}{\mu_0}\left[\mathbf{B}\times\mathbf{E}\right]\text{.}
\end{eqnarray*}$$
However, if one applies the following definitions of the auxilary fields $\mathbf{D}$, $\mathbf{H}$ (thus there is no need to assume a linear dielectric, etc.):
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
\epsilon_0\mathbf{E} = \mathbf{D}-\mathbf{P},&\quad&\frac{1}{\mu_0}\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{H} + \mathbf{M}
\end{eqnarray*}$$
to separate free and bound charges, the stress-energy tensor decomposes into (the first and second square-bracketed terms correspond to the free and bound terms, respectively):
$$\begin{eqnarray*}
-T_0{}^0 &=& \frac{1}{2}\left[\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathbf{D} + \mathbf{B}\cdot\mathbf{H}\right] + \frac{1}{2}\left[-\mathbf{E}\cdot\mathbf{P}+\mathbf{B}\cdot\mathbf{M}\right]\text{,}\\
+T_a{}^0 &=& \left[\mathbf{D}\times\mathbf{B}\right] + \left[-\mathbf{P}\times\mathbf{B}\right]\text{,}\\
-T_0{}^a &=& \left[\mathbf{E}\times\mathbf{H}\right] + \left[\mathbf{E}\times\mathbf{M}\right]\text{,}
\end{eqnarray*}$$
as well as a more complicated "Maxwell stress" terms in the space-space components.

Thus, fundamentally situation is (anti)symmetric, but the apparent break is due to a conventional decomposition to free and bound charges. In terms of the full stress-tensor tensor, $\mathbf{D}\times\mathbf{B}$ is part of the *field momentum density*, while $\mathbf{E}\times\mathbf{H}$ is part of *energy flux density*. The latter is the standard Poynting vector, but because of antisymmetry, the choice of which to use is actually arbitrary, so long as it's consistently applied.

Answer (score 1):

Since Poynting vector S

$$\vec{S}=\vec{E}\times \vec{H}$$ and 
$$\vec{H}=\frac{\vec{k}\times \vec{E}}{\mu\omega}$$

$\vec{S}$ is symmetric in $\vec{E}$ and $\vec{H}$ because

If $\vec{E} \rightarrow -\vec{E}$ then $\vec{H}$ also change its direction and  $\vec{H} \rightarrow -\vec{H}$ and vice-versa.

So  $\vec{S}$ is symmetric about $\vec{E}$ as
for $\vec{E} \rightarrow -\vec{E} \Rightarrow \vec{H} \rightarrow -\vec{H} $

so $$\vec{S}=\vec({-E})\times \vec({-H})$$
$$\vec{S}=\vec{S}$$

and similarly for $\vec{H}$.

And another point is that poynting vector is always in the direction of $\vec{k}$ in vacuum.

Comment: I don't think expression you've written for $\vec H$ in terms of $\vec E$ is general; one can in principle have all sorts of strange constitutive relations.

Answer (score 0):

When you say

> ...so I would think that any equation using magnetic and electric fields should be symmetric in E/B or D/H

You're taking the "correspondence" between these pairs too far.  It is easy to construct all sorts of electrodynamical identities in which, $\mathbf E$ and $\mathbf H$ appear together.  For example, using Ampere's Law in a medium
\begin{align}
  \nabla\times\mathbf H - \frac{\partial \mathbf D}{\partial t} = \mathbf J 
\end{align}
and some vector calculus, it is possible to show that
\begin{align}
  \frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + \nabla\cdot (\mathbf E\times\mathbf H) = -\mathbf J \cdot \mathbf E
\end{align}
where $u$ is the energy density in the fields, and $\mathbf J\cdot \mathbf E$ is the work per unit volume performed by the fields on whatever charges are present.  This equation is essentially a statement of the conservation of energy for electrodynamics.  This motivates the definition
\begin{align}
  \mathbf S = \mathbf E\times\mathbf H
\end{align}
which has the interpretation of the energy per unit area per unit time being carried by the electromagnetic fields.  Of course, homogeneous, isotropic, linear dielectric, for example, $\mathbf H = \mathbf B/\mu$ so that
\begin{align}
  \mathbf S = \frac{1}{\mu}\mathbf E\times\mathbf B
\end{align}
in which case you have your wish that $\mathbf E$ and $\mathbf B$ appear together.  In particular, in vacuum this is the case.

Comment: But now why do we only have a $\mu$ and no $\epsilon$?

Comment: @Anthony The presence, or lack thereof, of $\epsilon$ in the last expression for $\mathbf S$ in a linear dielectric depends on whether you decide to write it in terms of $\mathbf E$ or $\mathbf D = \epsilon \mathbf E$.  In the latter choice, we would have $\mathbf S = \frac{1}{\epsilon\mu}\mathbf D\times \mathbf B$.  Also, there is no rule of electrodynamics that says "in linear media, any equation written in terms of $\mathbf E$ and $\mathbf B$ must contain both $\epsilon$ and $\mu$."  In short, your expectations about how equations "should" look are too high and not supported by the math.